Build failed with these following exceptions
Execution failed for task ':camera_android_camerax:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':camera_android_camerax:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
Error while executing process F:\Android std (yahan he)\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

I'm trying to run my app with an import camera package 0.11.0+2, Project is running properly without importing package, but can't run with importing this packages.
I'm running on my Android Mobile phone whose version is 10, not on an emulator.
Gradle version 8.3
flutter version 3.24.5
Dart version 3.5.4
Jdk version 21.0.5
